# Authenticating a Web Service

Tags: asp.net, authentication, ssl, service

We are deploying our ASP.NET 3.5 app to a production server for beta testing.

Each page is secured using SSL.

On our homepage (default.aspx) we have web services which populate flash objects.

I am getting an error:

The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'.

Also, when using firefox, receive the Windows Login pop up screen.

Does anyone have any clue what or why this is happening?

Much thanks!

Comment: It could be this: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?kbid=326985

Comment: Is your web service and application hosted on the same or different servers?

Answer (score 1):

I would think that the request from Flash to the secure web services doesn't have credentials or that the secure certificate in the response can't be validated.

Probably both.

So in flash there will probably need to be some code like:

```
request.Username = "xyz"
request.Password = "***"
```

or something similar

In .net there is a way to manually override the validation of a certificate for the request. I'm not sure how you would do that in Flash.

I'll update this if I find a sample for the .net way.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like IIS isn't configured for [anonymous access](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/9ded7af2-fcb7-4ed2-b007-e19f971f6e13.mspx?mfr=true).

If you believe you have it setup correctly (sounds like it isn't), then you might try troubleshooting your connection with [Wfetch](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/284285).

Comment: I wish it was that easy.  It is setup for Anonymous Access.

Comment: Did you also grant access to the directory (and other resources) to the anonymous user account?